In Scala or other JVM language, which type declaration is closest to a type declaration nested in a generic class in C# or C++?
(this is the Scala version, for Rust version, please go to In Rust, which type declaration is closest to a type declaration nested in a generic class in C# or C++?)
When writing a library that relies heavily on generic/template in C# or C++, one trick I often use is to declare several structs that uses the same generic type arguments as nested types under a static class.
e.g. these declaration (using C# as an example):
    public struct Gen1<T1, T2, T3>
    {
    }

    public struct Gen2<T1, T2, T3>
    {
    }

is functionally equivalent to this:
    public static class Ts<T1, T2, T3>
    {
        public struct Gen1
        {
        }

        public struct Gen2
        {
        }
    }

Namely, Ts<int, int, string>.Gen1 is converted to a specialised class by the compiler, with its own static members. Ts<int, int, String> and Ts<int, int, int> becomes 2 different classes that shares nothing except names.
This is different from JVM compiler with type erasure, where type arguments are removed during the compilation. As a result, the same static nested class declaration translated to Java only has 1 type and has to be initialised without type arguments.
To my knowledge, no other JVM language has transcended this limitation (namely, Kotlin compiler doesn't support specialising a generic type like C#/C++, Scala compiler doesn't have static declaration and template/generic type argument for object type). In fact, most other languages don't have similar abstraction (the only exception is LEAN4, where the static generic class becomes a section: https://lean-lang.org/lean4/doc/sections.html).
I'm looking for a minimal extension to the type system of Scala/Kotlin that can reproduce this abstraction line-by-line. Given that Scala has path-dependent type and GADT, it will be my first choice. But how should I do this?
(One way to implement this without compiler plugin is to introduce a type equality axiom, I don't know how to do this, but if you answered In Scala 3 with DOT calculus, how to extend the equality of 2 path dependent types for obviously cases?, it should be easy to include the solution to this problem as a special case)

Why do you need Gen1 and Gen2 to generate multiple classes at all? - Classes, should be a runtime detail, your program logic should not care about classes but types.

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I don't, they are just there to demonstrate the repetitive declarations, in other's LEAN4 example they are functions

JVM allow you to avoid type erasure - trait Generic[A] -> trait Specific extends Generic[String] - when you create an instance of Specific it should keep the type param applied in the bytecode. You need to create a new subclass for that, even but even anonymous class count. So you could write inline def/macro which would create an anonymous class at call site with type params applied and available in runtime (including reflection). I am still not sure though what problem you are actually solving and if that would help.

@tribbloid I mean, in Scala you can also next classes inside another classes, and any repetitive declaration could be abstracted. So I really don't understand what is the problem you are trying to solve?

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that feature is dependent type and behave quite differently (LEAN4 has both dependent type and section). For a section, every instance with identical type argument is itself identical

I can think of two ways to implement this in Scala. Please try below and check if it helps:

Type members within class or trait:
 object MyObject {
     trait Base[T1, T2, T3] {
         type Gen1
         type Gen2
     }

     class Implementation[T1, T2, T3] extends Base[T1, T2, T3] {
         type Gen1 = (T1, T2, T3) 
         type Gen2 = (T1, T2, T3)
     }

     def create[T1, T2, T3]: Implementation[T1, T2, T3] = new Implementation[T1, T2, T3]
 }   


 //USAGE:

 val instance = MyObject.create[Int, String, Double]
 val gen1: instance.Gen1 = (42, "example", 3.14)
 println(gen1)
 val gen2: instance.Gen2 = (42, "example", 3.14)
 println(gen2)


Types using absolute paths:
object MyObject {
    class Ts[T1, T2, T3] {
        class Gen1 {
            def info(): String = s"Gen1 with T1: $T1, T2: $T2, T3: $T3"
        }

        class Gen2 {
            def info(): String = s"Gen2 with T1: $T1, T2: $T2, T3: $T3"
        }
   }   
}

//USAGE:
val instance = new MyObject[Int, String, Double]
val gen1Instance = new instance.Gen1
println(gen1Instance.info())
val gen2Instance = new instance.Gen2
println(gen2Instance.info())




Sorry this answer still only achieved dependent types, as I have pointed out in my discussion, section/C# specialised generic has a different behaviour
